# void pointer cast to a char pointer crashes when dereferencing

Tags: c, pointers, char, dereference

I'm trying to implement DJB algorithim in C to build a dictionary like structure.

My implementation works well if the key passed is a char pointer however if i pass for example a integer it crashes, I'm not sure why and how could i accomplish this. Basically I'd need to hash both a string and a integer.

```
static unsigned int DJBHash(void* key, unsigned int len) {
    unsigned int hash = 5381;
    unsigned int i = 0;
    char* ptr = (char *)key;

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {   
        hash += hash << 5;
        hash += *ptr;         /* crashes if key is not originally a char* */
        ptr++;
    }   

    return hash;
}
```

this get simply called to get an hash value:
`DJBHash((void*)420, sizeof(420));` crashses while `DJB((void*)"foo", sizeof("foo"));` works perfectly fine.

Comment: Why would you expect casting to the wrong type to work?

Comment: casting it only changes the pointer arithmetic as far as i understood, i don't understand how that would make it impossible to get a value when dereferencing

Comment: What is `key` ?

Comment: How about: a *pointer* to integer...?

Comment: Wouldn't `char* ptr = (char *)&key;` make more sense?

Comment: @jpo38 certainly not.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: If `key` is a `int` and `len` is `sizeof(int)` then you can iterate through the `int` content as `char`s...

Comment: What data do you pass to the function for `key`?

Comment: Sorry didn't notice that i forgot to put the signature, key is a void pointer because it needs to be as generic as possible

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: Now we know `key` may be a `int*` but not a `int`, you are right.

Comment: @AlanCasanova: Post more code. How do you call `DJBHash` when it crashs?

Comment: @jpo38 "key passed is a char pointer however if i pass for example a integer it crashes" - I guess that's self-evident. :/

Comment: Your problem is not in the cast. Post the erst of your code. You crash because you pass the pointer to the memory which is not allocated or you exceed its size

Comment: Please always enable warnings in your compiler. If you pass `420` while an address is expected, the compiler should warn you. An integer is not a pointer.

Comment: I've checked and it crashes exactly in the line where i do: hash += *ptr, ptr does not point to null so how could it not find any value at that memory adress?

Comment: That's the famous "Garbage in, garbage out" mechanism. If you try to use a number as an address, that's what might happen

Comment: When i use that function i cast both int and string to void * , my fault i forgot to mention that

Comment: Casting a number to a pointer type does not make it a pointer. It simple defeats sanity mechanisms in the compiler

Comment: Also: `sizeof("foo")` might not do what you expect. Try `sizeof("rather long text")` and compare with your expectations

Comment: @Gerhardh thank you, I thought that was going to simply work. I fixed the code keeping in mind what you pointed out and worked perfectly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DJBHash(420, sizeof(420));` crashses while `DJB("foo", sizeof("foo"));` works perfectly fine.

That's because using `420` isn't a valid memory address in your program.  So when your function tries to use that memory address it crashes.  Normally you wouldn't even try to force a specific memory address in this fashion.  It only works in very specific cases like when its a known address in kernel space or something like that.

If you want to hash an integer instead of specific memory location it would be:

```
int j = 420;
DJBHash(&j, sizeof(j));
```

Comment: Thanks, that was something I didn't know about C, still pretty new to this language and I was taking for granted that that was going to simply work.

Comment: @AlanCasanova This may be helpful:  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/memory-layout-of-c-program/

Comment: very helpfull indeed, appreciated.